# ESP8266 wdt reset

Tags: esp8266, watchdog

I just bought a KS0354 ESp8266 board to make a remote control for my iot project. Not sure why I keep on getting a wdt error. Even before I can complete my entire code I start getting this error. Below is my code:

```
int PIN_BUTTON_A = 2; 
int PIN_BUTTON_B = 3;
int PIN_BUTTON_C = 4;
int PIN_BUTTON_D = 5;
int PIN_BUTTON_E = 6;
int PIN_BUTTON_F = 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_B, INPUT);  
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_E, INPUT);  
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_C, INPUT);  
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_D, INPUT);  
  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_A, INPUT);  
}

void loop() {
   Serial.print("Buttons A:");
   delay(5000);

}
```

This seems to be a very simple code. Not sure what is wrong here. Below is the error I am getting @115200 baud rate:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,6)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 3584, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xb0
csum 0xb0
v2843a5ac
~ld
```

Does anyone has any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: has the module a 40 MHz clock? the bootlog at 115200 indicates that. then you must set it in Tools menu. or you did set 40 MHz and it has a 26MHz clock?